# Query in SQL errors out in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database, sqlite

This query works on SQL:

```
UPDATE Tech_Share_Attendance
SET (Match_Date) = (Tech_Share.Date)
FROM Tech_Share
WHERE Tech_share.TechShare_ID = Tech_Share_Attendance.Tech_Share_ID;
```

I receive a runtime error within Excel:

> (80004005) "near FROM: syntax error (1).

My VBA:

```vb
strsql = "UPDATE Tech_Share_Attendance SET Match_Date = Tech_Share.Date FROM Tech_Share WHERE Tech_Share.TechShare_ID = Tech_Share_Attendance.Tech_Share_ID"
```

I've looked into other posts where they include quotations or apostrophes. When I use them, I receive a missing object error.

Edit #1 - Full Code:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click()
Unload frmTechShare_Attend
frmTechShare_Lookup.Show
End Sub

Private Sub lblName_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub listRotations_Click()
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Name As String
Name = getAssociateName()
lblName.Caption = Name

AssociateID = getAssociateID()
ContactKey = getContactKey()

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

' OPEN CONNECTION
conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=\\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx;"
 strsql = "UPDATE Tech_Share_Attendance SET Match_Date = [Tech_Share.Date] FROM Tech_Share WHERE Tech_Share.TechShare_ID = Tech_Share_Attendance.Tech_Share_ID"
 ' strsql = "SELECT * FROM Tech_Share_Attendance T WHERE T.Contact_Key = " + Str(ContactKey) + " ORDER BY T.Tech_Share_ID"
' OPEN RECORDSET[
Debug.Print (strsql)
rst.Open strsql, conn

If rst.EOF = False Then
    With Me.listAttendance
        .Clear
        Do
            Tech_Share_ID = rst![Tech_Share_ID]
            Match_Date = rst![Match_Date]
            .AddItem (Tech_Share_ID + " | " + Match_Date)
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop Until rst.EOF
    End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub listAttendance_Click()
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd try using `Tech_Share.[Date]` instead of `Tech_Share.Date` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Rory , I tried usng Tech_Share.[Date] & [Tech_Share.Date] with no luck. Thank you for the comment, though! I didn't think about trying that.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: @Rory . I've edited to post the full code. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: An update query doesn't return a recordset, so try using `conn.execute strsql` instead, with your original SQL.

Comment: The UPDATE FROM syntax is supported since version 3.33.0 of SQLite. Check your version.

Comment: @Rory , @forpas , Thank you for the help! The execute and the UPDATE FROM syntax really helped. I was able to get it worked out with this set of code. 

```
conn.Execute "UPDATE [Tech_Share_Attendance] SET [Match_Date] = (SELECT [Date]" & _
 " FROM [Tech_Share]" & _
 " WHERE [TechShare_ID] = [Tech_Share_ID]);"
```